# How to verify a Postback with Skadnetwork/Apple

Tags: postback, x509, skadnetwork

I'm having issues to verify a postback with Skadnetwork/Apple according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork/verifying_an_install_validation_postback) Apple is giving out.

There are two issues I have (at least I think there are only two issues).

1. `\u2063` - I'm using a PHP to grab all the information from a POST and then create the string for later verification. Sadly I'm not sure if the `\u2063` should simply be there in the string or if it should there be in some encoded/decoded way.
2. The Apple Public Key - How should it be used. The version that is seen in the documentation in some decoded/encoded way. Docs say decode base 64 and then create X.509 standard public key from that.

Does anyone have a working example? At the moment I'm complete lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im using NodeJS and it was pretty simple. I took Apple's public key and wrapped it with `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n` and `\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
<APPLE_PUBLIC_KEY_BASE_64 (copy paste from Apple's guide)>
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Or you can use NodeJs crypto module to load the public key:

```js
const key = Buffer.from(`<APPLE_PUBLIC_KEY_BASE_64 (copy paste from Apple's guide)>`, 'base64');
const publicKey = crypto.createPublicKey({
  key,
  format: 'der',
  type: 'spki',
});
```

Then I concatenated the parts of the postback that are needed for the verification with `\u2063` separator.

```js
// ad network version 2.0/2.1
const message = [
  version,
  adNetworkId,
  campaignId,
  appId,
  transactionId,
  redownload,
].join('\u2063');
```

Then I used NodeJS crypto module to verify the signature:

```js
const verify = crypto.createVerify('sha256');
verify.update(message);
verify.verify(publicKey, signature, 'base64'); // this returns a boolean
```

This can be done in a similar way with [Singular-SKAdNetwork-App](https://github.com/singular-labs/Singular-SKAdNetwork-App) `ECDSA` wrapper class from [here](https://github.com/singular-labs/Singular-SKAdNetwork-App/blob/master/skadnetwork-server/ecdsa_wrapper.py)

```py
SEPERATOR = u"\u2063"

postback = {
    "version": "2.1",
    "ad-network-id": "com.example",
    "campaign-id": 42,
    "transaction-id": "6aafb7a5-0170-41b5-bbe4-fe71dedf1e28",
    "app-id": 525463029,
    "attribution-signature": "MEUCID6rbq3qt4GvFaAaynh5/LAcvn1d8CQTRhrZhLIxLKntAiEAo7IrvoMw6u2qDg6Tr5vIsEHXjlLkPlCOL0ojJcEh3Qw=",
    "redownload": True,
    "source-app-id": 1234567891,
    "conversion-value": 20
}

pub_key = """
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEWdp8GPcGqmhgzEFj9Z2nSpQVddayaPe4FMzqM9wib1+aHaaIzoHoLN9zW4K8y4SPykE3YVK3sVqW6Af0lfx3gg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
"""

message = (
    postback["version"]
    + SEPERATOR
    + postback["ad-network-id"]
    + SEPERATOR
    + str(postback["campaign-id"])
    + SEPERATOR
    + str(postback["app-id"])
    + SEPERATOR
    + postback["transaction-id"]
    + SEPERATOR
    + str(postback["redownload"]).lower()
    + SEPERATOR
    + str(postback["source-app-id"])
)

ecdsa = ECDSA(pub_key)
signature = postback["attribution-signature"]
ecdsa.verify(message, signature) # this returns a boolean
```

I hope this will help. I don't have any experience with PHP :/

Comment: Thanks a lot - that helped me a lot. I was able to include the Python version into my code.