# Verify Apple's signature

Tags: python, cryptography, x509, public-key

I'm trying to verify a signature according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork/verifying_an_install-validation_postback#3599761). Here is an example:

```
# cryptography==37.0.4
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec
import base64

data = b"demo data"
signature = b"demo signature"

public_key_base64 = "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEWdp8GPcGqmhgzEFj9Z2nSpQVddayaPe4FMzqM9wib1+aHaaIzoHoLN9zW4K8y4SPykE3YVK3sVqW6Af0lfx3gg=="
public_key_bytes = base64.b64decode(public_key_base64)
apple_public_key = ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point(ec.SECP256R1(), public_key_bytes)

apple_public_key.verify(
    signature,
    data,
    ec.ECDSA(hashes.SHA256())
)
```

`from_encoded_point` generates:

```
    raise ValueError("Unsupported elliptic curve point type")
ValueError: Unsupported elliptic curve point type
```

Also tried different approaches from `chat GPT` but none works. Could you provide a working example please?

Comment: JFYI: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496534/how-to-verify-a-postback-with-skadnetwork-apple), [verifier](https://github.com/d-ganchar/vap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key appears to be a base64 encoded [SubjectPublicKeyInfo](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.1) formatted public key. The cryptography module provide a general method for decoding these for all the public key types it supports via the [`cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/#key-loading) module. Thus, the fix is simply to replace

```py
apple_public_key = ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point(ec.SECP256R1(), public_key_bytes)
```

with the much simpler

```py
apple_public_key = serialization.load_der_public_key(public_key_bytes)
```

and of course add `serialization` to the relevant import statement:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
```